# SQL query which return counted results from many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, where-in

I have two tables 'shops' and 'products'. Shop has many products and product belongs to one shop. Moreover product belongs to the only one category. I have id's of 3 categories (for example 1,2,3). How can I get all shops having products which belongs to all 3 categories?

I tried

```
SELECT distinct s.*
from shops s
left join products p on p.shop_id = s.id
where p.category_id in (1,2,3)
```

but this returns shops with products which belongs to the category 1 OR 2 OR 3 But I want the products which belongs to the all 3 categories like 1 AND 2 AND 3, so every shop have to have at least 3 products

Comment: There's really no point outer joining a table from which you select no columns

Comment: As it happens, this is an inner join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the s.id having count(distinct p.category_id) = 3

```
SELECT  s.id 
from shops s
inner join products p on p.shop_id = s.id
where p.category_id in (1,2,3)
group by s.id
having count(distinct p.category_id) = 3
```

Comment: you saved my life :)

Comment: It's still an inner join though

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*
  from shops s
  join products p 
    on p.shop_id = s.id
 where p.category_id in (1,2,3)
 Group 
    by s.id
Having count(distinct p.category_id) = 3
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID FROM SHOPS A, PRODUCTS B
WHERE A.ID = B.SHOP_ID AND EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PRODUCTS C, PRODUCTS D, PRODUCTS E WHERE B.ID = C.ID AND C.ID = D.ID AND D.ID = E.ID AND C.CATEGORY_ID = 1 AND D.CATEGORY_ID = 2 AND E.CATEGORY_ID = 3)
```

My T-SQL is rusty and this assumes I got the relations correct such that Shops 1 - M Products and, I'm unsure if Category is an entity but Category 1 - M Product.  Also, just for future work, I've found it helps when your entities are names singular nouns but that's just my preference.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Use group by will return by each shop

```
SELECT distinct s.*
from shops s
left join products p on p.shop_id = s.id
where p.category_id in (1,2,3)
group by s.id
having count(distinct p.category_id) = 3
```